# ScrollView not enabling scrolling in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Using Expo and the Android App, the `<ScrollView>` section is not scrolling. I've read through a lot of related questions but can't seem to nail down the issue. Can anyone shed some light for a react native newbie?

On pressing the button the API is requested and then the article headlines are rendered. This all works great but the headlines are not scrollable and don't all fit on the screen. Am I misunderstanding what `<ScrollView>` does?

```
import React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Footer } from 'react-native'
import { Font } from 'expo'
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontLoaded: true,
    buttonPressed: false,
    showButton: true
  }

  onPress = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.fetchArticlesAsync()
    this.setState({
      buttonPressed: true, 
      showButton: false
    })
  }

  async fetchArticlesAsync() {
    await fetch('http://content.guardianapis.com/search?show-fields=all&api-key=d8d8c012-6484-4bb4-82d7-2770a7c5d029')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJSON => {
      return this.setState({
        articleList: responseJSON.response.results
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {
        this.state.fontLoaded &&
        <View style={this.state.buttonPressed ? styles.newsContainer : styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Newsli</Text>
          {this.state.showButton && 
          <Button buttonStyle={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress} clear text='Feed Me' />}
          {this.state.buttonPressed &&
          <View>
            {this.state.articleList ?
            <View style={styles.articleContainer}>
            {this.state.articleList.map((article, i) => {
              return <View style={styles.articleContainer} key={i}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{article.webTitle}</Text>
                </View>
            })}
            </View> : <Text style={styles.loading}>Loading</Text>}
          </View>}
        </View>
      }
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  newsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 15
  },
  articleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 15
  },
  header: { 
    fontSize: 90,
    color: '#fff'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#fff',
  },
  loading: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#FF69B4'
  },
  button: {
    borderColor: '#fff', 
    borderWidth: 2
  }
})
```

Comment: Try paddingVertical: 20 to scrollview container

Answer (score 3):

It was quite small mistake. The ScrollView does not know current device's screen size. You need to have ScrollView inside a View component. Try the following...

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
      {...}
      </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Next time when you submit a question strip out all nonsense code. Like Font fetching. 
Good luck!

Comment: Please upvote or mark as correct if it was useful. No worries about the junk was quite easy to strip out but. But it makes the question look to long.

Comment: So it seemed to work to an extent. It can now scroll but it doesn't 'stick' in that it snaps back to the default position.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stick'. In my version with two different iOS simulators. I can stop the scroll att any point and it stays in that position.

Comment: Yeah that's not happening for me, how weird. I'm using the iPhoneX version, I'll try another.